# Topic Challenge

Tags: support, feature-request, events

@Roflcopter just pointed out https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ which has a big "Topic Challenge" banner at the top.  We like the idea - how would this be possible to configure for Travel.SE?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out to be a System Message.  Case Closed.

Comment: What does that mean - only our SE overlords can send it?

Comment: Apparently it's a moderator ability...

Comment: Please note that the system message that Judaism puts up is an abuse of that functionality. They've been asked not to use it for their weekly topic challenge; system messages were designed for rare but important announcements like moderator elections, planned site down time, etc. - not for weekly events.

Comment: ah...blast.  So is there any other way to have something like that, aside from simply making a post in meta?

Comment: And when do you think we should start with it?

Comment: @MarkMayo Not at the moment, but since a lot of sites have expressed a need for some sort of announcement tool other than the system message, we're discussing options for what we can build. It'll probably be a while before there's any new tool, so for now, your best bet is to make a meta post and a chat event.

Comment: Sweet, that's what I've done as a test for the next few days.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As Mark Mayo pointed out, it is a System Message. Since we shouldn't use this, how about using an Event? Events are also displayed on the main site.